# Derivation: Entropy of Vaporisation using Redlich-Kwong EoS

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, physical-chemistry

[image]

The part I'm stuck on is the last part. Basically, the question is to obtain the following equation for the entropy of vaporisation using the Redlich-Kwong equation:
$$
\Delta S = R\Bigg[ \ln \frac{V_2 -b}{V_1 - b} \Bigg] + \frac{0.5a}{bT^{1.5}}\ln \Bigg[ \frac{V_2(V_1-b)}{V_1(V_2-b)} \Bigg]
$$

Solution Attempt:

I think I should start by using the known fact that at equilibrium, the free energy of both phases must be the same. Using Gibbs free energy:
$$
dG = -SdT + VdP \implies -S_1dT + V_1dP = -S_2dT + V_2dP
$$
Therefore, I can write an equation for change in entropy due to vaporisation:
$$
S_1 - S_2 = (V_1 - V_2)\frac{dP}{dT}
$$
However when I simply differentiate the given EoS and multiply by $V_1 - V_2$ I don't get the same result. Clearly, in the answer they have integrated wrt v at some point but I just don't get why or how. Any help will be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: You correctly wrote "at equilibrium, the free energy of both phases must be the same" but your corresponding equation says the the *change* in the Gibbs free energy must be the same, which is not equivalent.

Comment: @Chemomechanics hmm, should it be dG_1 = -dG_2 ?

Comment: $ΔG=G_1−G_2=0$ for the individual phases and $dG=0$ for the entire system, from which you can derive that $\mu_1=\mu_2$. But anyway, to solve for the entropy of each phase at the constant-temperature phase transition, try writing $dS=\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial T}\right)_V\,dT+\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial V}\right)_T\,dV=\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial V}\right)_T\,dV$ and using a Maxwell relation. If this is agreeable, I'll write it out as an answer for your approval.

Comment: @Chemomechanics Yes please! My only concern is the limits of integration. Seemingly, they will be $V_L$ for the lower limit and $V_V$ for the upper. However, the EoS doesn't work for liquids, it can only predict gas behaviour,  so how can we put down $V_L$ as a limit in the integration?

Comment: My understanding is that the Redlich-Kwong equation (and its modifications) is a special case of an equation of state that reasonably describes both the gaseous and liquid states, which is probably why it was selected for your problem.

Comment: Ah, gotcha, thank you. I can finish it off myself now, if you write an answer I'll give you best answer though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason that the equations don't match is that the free energy of both phases being equal (which is an accurate statement) is not equivalent to their $dG$ values being equal. One way to see this is to note that although the gas and liquid free energy curves coincide at a phase transition, [their slopes are not equal](http://casey.brown.edu/chemistry/misspelled-researh/crp/Edu/Documents/00_Chem201/images/Minima_of_the_Gibbs_potential_.gif).

A better approach is to express the entropy $S$ as a function of $T$ and $V$ (i.e., $dS=\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial T}\right)_V\,dT+\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial V}\right)_T\,dV$, which is simply $\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial V}\right)_T\,dV$ at the constant-temperature condition of a first-order phase transition. Using the Maxwell relation $\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial V}\right)_T=\left(\frac{\partial P}{\partial T}\right)_V$, it's relatively straightforward to obtain the intended expression for $S$ and then for $\Delta S$.

More expressions for systems following the Redlich-Kwong equation of state are given [here](http://www.znaturforsch.com/aa/v60a/s60a0783.pdf).